# Token Authentication for remote windows session

Tags: c#, token, impersonation

We are building an application whereby a C# api on server **A** is sending domain credentials securely to C# slaves drones (processing applications) on Servers B1,B2,B3...,Bn.

Each drone is to process physical files on dynamic remote storages using provided credentials.

We are searching for a way to send credentials from Server A to Server B1,B2,B3...,Bn using a temporary token produced from server A username/password authentication.

Sending username/passwords is not desirable in case the drone gets compromised, but we haven't found a single use case whereby the token is produced from a server and sent to slaves drones.

The WindowsIdentity class does provide an accesstoken, but as the value returned is a handle and intPtr, it is not a viable solution for sending the result to remote drones.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4(v=vs.110).aspx

As access to physical files is required for processing, OAuth may also not be used to provide the expected result.

Is there any systems, known third library, or windows logic that could solve this use case?

Thanks in advance.